# where does truelicense persist the license file

Tags: java, licensing, license-key, truelicense

This question is very specific to the implementation of TrueLicense and its workings. With the help of the tutorials [here](http://truelicense.java.net/tutorial.html) and the more helpful [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/true-license-java-client-java-license-manager), I have successfully been able to apply licensing on my software using TrueLicense. However, I am still not clear on certain aspects of TrueLicense and how it works, and am hoping somebody can enlighten me. For now, what I don't understand is that when I call the

```
licenseManager.install()
```

method (making sure the rest of the prerequisites are fulfilled) where is the license file actually getting persisted. I know that it is getting persisted somehow because the second time I start the application and run the

```
licenseManager.verify()
```

method it returns happy. I would really appreciate some insight on this.

Comment: `File keyFile = new File("license.lic")` means it is in the current directory

Comment: We specify the license file when actually installing the license. But in subsequent runs of the application `licenseManager.verify()` returns successfully meaning the license is installed, but no file is specified here. Note, this time no license file is specified since it is not being installed. How does the licenseManager know where the license file is or how is this information persisted. I hope that clarifies my question.

Comment: Can truelicense be applied to application which is extension of open source third party application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source-code (TrueLicense):

```
/**
 * Installs the given license key as the current license key.
 * If {@code key} is {@code null}, the current license key gets
 * uninstalled (but the cached license certificate is not cleared).
 */
protected synchronized void setLicenseKey(final byte[] key) {
    final Preferences prefs = getLicenseParam().getPreferences();
    if (null != key)
        prefs.putByteArray(PREFERENCES_KEY, key);
    else
        prefs.remove(PREFERENCES_KEY);
}
```

If you use the standard Java preferences API ([java.util.prefs.Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html)), you will see this in the registry on Windows.  On Linux and OS X, there is a hidden "." directory that has these keys.

Typically, I just use the [userNodeForPackage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#userNodeForPackage%28java.lang.Class%29) method, since it does not require an admin on Windows.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about the late response, but this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Open regedit tool;
Under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/JavaSoft/Prefs/{$the.package.of.your.license.classes}.`

Note: this is only for windows and is the default behaviour. (with original `PREFERENCES_KEY` value)